# Agora.io voice call quickstart not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, agora.io

I followed this tutorial https://github.com/aryankush25/ReactNativeAgoraApp which I believe is the hooks equivalent to the agora.io voicemail quickstart guide https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/start_call_audio_react_native?platform=React%20Native however it won't work for some reason.

This is the error I run into (when running on an iOS simulator):

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'AgoraRtcChannelModule.prefix')
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The repo you mentioned is not an official Agora example, I wouldn't be able to help there. Maybe open a github issue.

However, you can use [this quickstart](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-RN-Quickstart) from the Agora community, you can comment out `await this._engine.enableVideo()` (line 65) and tweak the UI to make it audio only. You can adapt this to use functional components.

You can also check this [example app](https://github.com/EkaanshArora/Agora-RN-Audio-Broadcast/) for audio broadcasting.